# xPages dataTable page

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a data table on my xPage that shows e.g. 10 rows (repeat limit, rows="10").
How do I know what's the current page number when I navigate through the records by using pager?

After switching between pages I'd like to return back and open dataTable exactly on same page I left:

```
getComponent("dataTable1").gotoPage(<page number I save>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best route to get the behavior you want is to use the `<xe:pagerSaveState/>` control from the ExtLib, which does the job of storing the state of a given pager and restoring it when you go back to the page. Brad Balassaitis has an example of how to use it here: http://xcellerant.net/2013/08/08/xpages-data-views-6-pager-save-state-control/

Comment: Not sure it's what I need.. Especially when I navigate to another page and then return. Still need a method to save current page number...

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your needs, that's what the pagerSaveState does - it's meant to save and restore the current pager page number for when you travel to another page in the app and return. The important thing is to execute that line of SSJS from his post early in the page load, such as in beforePageLoad.